# Storing large character objects with attribute converter in JPA

Tags: java, jpa, orm, eclipselink

I am trying to store a `Map<Date,String>` with JPA. I am using JPA 2.2 with MariaDB on Payara 5.2020 with Java 11. I am using Eclipselink as provider.

I want to store the content of Map as JSON in DB. I have defined a converter for this sake. At the same time I also want the column type as a CLOB to support large JSON string. I have used `@Lob` annotation from JPA for this sake. In MariaDB it maps to `longtext`.

The problem I am facing is, if I use JPA Converter and Lob together, Lob is ignored completely and field is stored in DB as varchar. If I remove the converter, then Lob annotation is respected.

I would like to know why Lob annotation is ignored.I could not find anything specific after searching on Google.

Is it expected behavior? Has anyone faced this problem before?

Here is the converter skeleton

```
@Converter
public class TemporalLogJsonConverter implements AttributeConverter<Map<Date,String>,String> {

    @Override
    public String convertToDatabaseColumn(Map<Date,String> log) {
            //code to convert
        return "";
    }

    @Override
    public Map<Date,String> convertToEntityAttribute(String dbData) {
        return Collections.EMPTY_MAP;  //dummy code 
  }
}
```

Here is the entity skeleton

```
@Entity(name = "MYENTITY_TBL")
public class MyEntity implements Serializable{

@Id
private String id;

@Column(name="LOG")
@Convert(converter=TemporalLogJsonConverter.class)
@Lob
private Mat<Date,String> log;

}
```

Comment: Are you relying on it to set the DB column type for DDL? If so, have you tried specifying the column type @Column(columnDefinition="CLOB")

Comment: @Chris Thanks, I missed that part. It works when I add native SQL fragment in columnDefinition attribute. I am using MariaDB so I had to use 'longtext'. However, it becomes specific to the underlying database I am using. You may post as answer I will accept. Thanks

Comment: @Chris, It works with ColumnDefinition, but still I am curious to know why Converter and Lob doesn't work together.

Comment: Lob is treated as a special type of converter. Both can set the type, but I'm guessing your custom Convert one is last. Either it is blocking out the Lob annotation from being loaded, or is overriding the column type to String because that is what your converter returns.